# list merging with text-columns and fixed space before-and-after

Tags: lists, enumitem

I have 250 number of lists and using `enumitem` and `shortlst` packages. I have required all the list should align in the `leftside` and all the `item` spacing `before-and-after` should be fixed `5 points`. I have no need to use `multicol` package. I have used `\setlist` tag but texts are merging with `columns`.

How to avoid merging `columns` and `before-and-after` fixed spacing for any `enumerate` lists.

Please find the my MWE below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem,shortlst,tasks}

\makeatletter
\setlist[enumerate,1]    {label=\arabic*,align=left,font=\color{blue},leftmargin=15pt,labelwidth=10pt}
\setlist[enumerate,2]    {label=\alph*,align=left,font=\color{red},leftmargin=10pt}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\roman*,align=left,font=\color{violet}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=\Alph*,align=left,font=\color{green}}
\newenvironment{ansenumerate}[1][30]{%
  \setlength{\shortitemwidth}{#1pt}%
  \begin{shortenumerate}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
    \ifodd\value{@MCans}
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.3em}%
    \else
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{0.35em}%
    \fi
}{%
 \end{shortenumerate}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item $6+x=11$
\item $6x=14$
\item $3=q $
\item $6+a=10$
\item $12+b=15$
\item $0=3b+2$
\item $4=7 +a$
\item $12x+2=8$
\item $7p=12$
\item $1(x+4)=27$
\item $18=3(a+5)$
\item $2x+2=8$
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1]    
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item $26+x=11$
\item $2x+2=8$
\item $13=q $
\item $16+a=10$
\item $112+b=15$
\item $10=3b+2$
\item $14=7 +a$
\item $112x+2=8$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1]    
%%%
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item $6+x=11$
\item $6x=14$
\item $3=q $
\item $6+a=10$
\item $12+b=15$
\item $0=3b+2$
\item $4=7 +a$
\item $12x+2=8$
\item $7p=12$
\item $3(x+4)=27$
\item $18=3(a+5)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1]    
%%%%
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item $6+x=11$
\item $6x=14$
\item $3=q $
\item $6+a=10$
\item $12+b=15$
\item $0=3b+2$
\item $4=7 +a$
\item $12x+2=8$
\item $7p=12$
\item $3(x+4)=27$
\item $18=3(a+5)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a link for `shortlist.sty` if it is required. It is not on CTAN or part of TeX Live.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to do. You seem to have configured the first and second levels of enumeration so that they will inevitably clash. In fact, the second one starts to the left of the first, which doesn't make sense. Is the 5pt you mention *horizontal* spacing or *vertical* spacing?

Answer (score 2):

I've removed stuff related to the non-standard package since your document doesn't seem to depend on it. (I doubt it needs `tasks` either.)

There are 2 immediate issues. One is that you haven't activated Latin hyphenation patterns so TeX is unable to break lines sensibly and the narrowness of the text width causes stuff to spill over. This can be solved by specifying `latin` as a class option and loading `babel`.

The second is that you have configured the `enumerate` environment in a way which places the first and second level labels in almost the same place. A label for the second will be placed ***just*** to the right of the first, with no spacing at all. I take it that the results are not as desired. However, I'm not sure what effect you are trying to achieve. The following specifies a space of `5pt` before and after the label. Adjust and enjoy!

```
\documentclass[latin]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem,tasks,babel}

\setlist[enumerate] {align=left, labelindent=5pt, labelsep=5pt, leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,1]    {label=\arabic*,font=\color{blue}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]    {label=\alph*,font=\color{red}}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\roman*,font=\color{violet}}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label=\Alph*,font=\color{green}}

\begin{document}

  \twocolumn
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $6+x=11$
    \item $6x=14$
    \item $3=q $
    \item $6+a=10$
    \item $12+b=15$
    \item $0=3b+2$
    \item $4=7 +a$
    \item $12x+2=8$
    \item $7p=12$
    \item $1(x+4)=27$
    \item $18=3(a+5)$
    \item $2x+2=8$
  \end{enumerate}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item $26+x=11$
      \item $2x+2=8$
      \item $13=q $
      \item $16+a=10$
      \item $112+b=15$
      \item $10=3b+2$
      \item $14=7 +a$
      \item $112x+2=8$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \lipsum[1]
  %%%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item $6+x=11$
        \item $6x=14$
        \item $3=q $
        \item $6+a=10$
        \item $12+b=15$
        \item $0=3b+2$
        \item $4=7 +a$
        \item $12x+2=8$
        \item $7p=12$
        \item $3(x+4)=27$
        \item $18=3(a+5)$
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
  \lipsum[1]
  %%%%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item $6+x=11$
          \item $6x=14$
          \item $3=q $
          \item $6+a=10$
          \item $12+b=15$
          \item $0=3b+2$
          \item $4=7 +a$
          \item $12x+2=8$
          \item $7p=12$
          \item $3(x+4)=27$
          \item $18=3(a+5)$
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: lists and columns]